# writing a class inside a function in Python: No object

Tags: python-3.x, class, object

I am a bit confused with the definition of class inside a function.
Usually while defining class inside a function, we define it as follows:

```
def dude():
    class swaroop(object)
```

What if there is no object at all and the function goes like this:

```
def dude():
    class swaroop():
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Those are exactly equivalent, in Python 3.x.  In 2.x, inheriting from `object` instead of nothing gives a "new-style class", which has some minor behavioral differences from the old style (which has been dropped in 3.x).

Answer (score 0):

The `class(object)` syntax is an example of [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)). If you remove the inherited object, then the class that you create inherits from nothing and is therefore a new class. Because you're defining it within a function, it can only be used within that scope.